# Generating number with respect to DateTime

Tags: .net, vb.net

How do I generate a number from 1 to 9999 as a string appended to a DateTime and then start from 1 the next day?

e.g. `0001-24-07-2019`, `0002-24-07-2019`, `0003-24-07-2019` ... `9999-24-07-2019` then `0001-25-07-2019`, `0002-25-07-2019` ... `9999-25-07-2019` ...

```
xxxxno = ProjectManager.PrependZeros((CInt(_ProjectManager.GetTransID()) + 1).ToString, 6) & "-" & Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy-hh-mm-ss")

Dim xxxxno As String = Now.Millisecond.ToString() & New Random().Next(1000, 9999).ToString()
```

Comment: `Dim xxxxno As String` seems like VB rather than C#, also, I don't see an immediate connection to "asp" or "arrays"; you might want to adjust the tags.  That said, do you want the numbers to be consecutive? You're using `Random`, which seems like a contradiction. The approach would be to start with the number `1`, remember that number somehow, and keep incrementing it, everytime it is "used". Also remember, on what date that number was set to `1` and if the current date is different, set it to `1` again (and remember the new date).

Comment: @corak ...yes that is what i want to achieve that is starting a number with 1, remembering it and then incrementing it and then remember what date it is used so as to start with 1 in a different date...please i need help as am a newbie with .net

Comment: yes the code contradicts as i tried the two codes but never got the result

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your requirements correctly,  you may use something like the following:

```
Private lastUsedDate As Date
Private lastNumber As Integer

Private Function GenerateString() As String
    If lastUsedDate <> Today Then
        lastUsedDate = Today
        lastNumber = 0
    End If

    lastNumber += 1

    If lastNumber > 9999 Then
        ' TODO: Decide what you'd like to happen in this case.
    End If

    Return lastNumber.ToString("0000") & "-" & Today.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")
End Function
```

**Usage example:**

```
Sub Main()
    Do While True
        Console.ReadLine()
        Console.WriteLine(GenerateString())  ' 0001-20-02-2020, 0002-20-02-2020, etc.
    Loop
End Sub
```

The two fields `lastUsedDate` and `lastNumber` are declared at the class level so that their values are remembered each time you call `GenerateString()`.

If you'd like to remember the values after the program is closed/restarted, you may store them in the [application settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/developing-apps/programming/app-settings/). In that case, you'd use `My.Settings.LastUsedDate` and `My.Settings.LastNumber` instead. You should also call `My.Settings.Save()` where appropriate in order to save the settings.

Answer (score 0):

According to:

> e.g. `0001-24-07-2019`, `0002-24-07-2019`, `0003-24-07-2019` ... `9999-24-07-2019` then `0001-25-07-2019`, `0002-25-07-2019` ... `9999-25-07-2019` ...

I think the required snippet is:

```vb
Dim output As IEnumerable(Of String) = Enumerable.Range(0, 2).
    SelectMany(Function(x) Enumerable.Range(1, 9999).
    Select(Function(i) $"{i.ToString("0000")}-{Date.Now.AddDays(x).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")}"))

'For example
txtOutput.Lines = output.ToArray
```

To get something like:

```
0001-20-02-2020
0002-20-02-2020
0003-20-02-2020
.......continue
9998-20-02-2020
9999-20-02-2020
0001-21-02-2020
0002-21-02-2020
0003-21-02-2020
.......continue
9997-21-02-2020
9998-21-02-2020
9999-21-02-2020
```

And for the mentioned date range:

```vb
Dim output As IEnumerable(Of String) = Enumerable.Range(0, 2).
    SelectMany(Function(x) Enumerable.Range(1, 9999).
    Select(Function(i) $"{i.ToString("0000")}-{New DateTime(2019, 7, 24).AddDays(x).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")}"))

txtOutput.Lines = output.ToArray
```